# JS. setInterval does not increment value of variables in external scope

Tags: javascript, timer, closures

I trying to bring my timer update the value of all `let` variables. But unfortunally my `setInterval` fucntion does not want to do this.

Where is my problem located? Thanks

```js
      function defineInterval(intervalInHours = 1, precision = 3600, disableInterval = 900, time = 200000) {
        let interval = 0
        let timeLeftInInterval = 0
        let timePercent = 0
        let timeDisabled = 0

        setInterval(() => {
            interval = intervalInHours * precision;
            timeLeftInInterval = (time % interval);
            console.log(interval, 'interval', timeLeftInInterval, 'timeLeftInInterval ', timeDisabled, 'timeDisabled', timePercent, 'timePercent') // 3600, 2000, 1600, 59 on output
            
            if (disableInterval >= timeLeftInInterval) {
                timeDisabled = disableInterval - timeLeftInInterval;
                timePercent = (timeDisabled / disableInterval) * 100;
            } else {
                timeDisabled = interval - timeLeftInInterval;
                timePercent = (timeDisabled / (interval++ - disableInterval) * 100);
                interval++
            }
        }, 1000)
      }

      defineInterval();
```

Comment: Please describe how you expect those variables to change over time.

Comment: FWIW, it probably all stems from you _resetting `interval` to a constant value_ in the first line of the callback function.

Comment: `intervalInHours * precision` never changes, so `interval` won't. `time` never changes, so `timeLeftInInterval` won't. I'm not sure what you're expecting here :/ Have you considered debugging it?

Comment: @Alnitak I said about all four variabbles -         `let interval = 0`
        `let timeLeftInInterval = 0`
       `let timePercent = 0`
       `let timeDisabled = 0` - they always in timer equal to their own value

Comment: Please read my comment again.   They always equal those values _because that's what your code does_.    You need to describe the _expected values of those variables_, because as written we can't guess at the intended behaviour of your code.   And don't just say "I want the numbers to change".   Describe _how_ they should change.

Comment: @MaxTravis At least two people said that you're setting `interval` to a constant, which affects the rest of your calculations. I even told you why. Again: debugging is your friend. Step through the loop. Write it down on paper--play computer and actually understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. `interval = intervalInHours * precision;` is getting reset to 3600 every time. Move it above setInterval.
2. You are not doing anything to change values in `if` statement, it's not impacting anything. Changing `timeDisabled` and `timePercent` is not impacting anything further. It will give same values after every timeout. Are you missing an `interval++`?
3. You are doing `interval++` two times in your `else` statement.